# When is the appropriate time to call DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache?

Tags: vb6, dao

Using DAO in VB6, which of the two examples is the most sensible use of `DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache`?

Example 1:

```
customers.Index = "primarykey"
customers.Seek "=", this_date, supplier
DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache
```

Example 2:

```
DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache
customers.Index = "primarykey"
customers.Seek "=", this_date, supplier
```

Comment: Depends when you want the cache refreshed :) Seriously, what other answer can we give?

Comment: Before or after a `.Seek` call?  I would think before, but I am looking at legacy code that has it after, so I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `customers` is an ADO [recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? So example 2 (refresh cache first) would make more sense.

`DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache` [is used to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180223) synchronize reading and writing between two processes. The ADO Recordset [`Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) operation search is more likely to show up changes made by another process if you issue `DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache` before the `Seek`.

I guess one question is whether there really is another process changing the data? Or (possibly) another database connection from the same program? If not, there's no need to refresh the cache at all.

Comment: It is a multi workstation system so there will be other processes accessing the database.